# Фон DateTimePicker в Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Почему на компоненты DateTimePicker в Delphi (любой версии; я работаю в XE7) не меняются фон компонента? В поздних версиях XE появилась опция управлять стилями, но и там эти изменения обходят стороной вышеописанный компонент. Свойство `Color` и его раздел `ColColor` никак не влияет на изменение цвета календаря+времени. Читал, что это баг делфи на форуме, хотя сомневаюсь в этом. Кто решал эту проблему? Мелочь, но досадная, хотелось бы исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TDateTimerPicker` — это обёртка над стандартным контролом `SysDateTimePick32` (`DATETIMEPICK_CLASS`). Он отличается тем, что не поддерживает стилизацию при использовании современных стилей. Чтобы стилизация поддерживалась, нужно вручную всё отрисовывать, и этого, разумеется, стараются избежать, если нет особой нужды.

Несколько решений представлено в ответе на вопрос [Style properties for TDateTimePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335310/style-properties-for-tdatetimepicker/10338248#10338248).

Comment: Спасибо, мне это пригодилось!